# Generate a dynamic "video" in real time, with the data entered?

Tags: javascript, css

On this page I enter the data for the "home loan simulation". and a "video" is generated in response to the data that I entered, it is something like a dynamic "video".

**This "video" shows related data that I entered.**

[image]

I inspect the code and I don't see anything that shows a video tag or something. This looks like video, from the control bar, to the full screen option, and the cc. It also has audio, although the voice of the "video" does not mention any dynamic data.

[image]

I inspect the code and I don't see anything that shows a video tag or something.
This looks like video, from the control bar, to the full screen option, and the cc. It also has audio, although the voice of the "video" does not mention any dynamic data.

Does anyone know how this was done or has an example of how to do it? is there any way to do the same using javascript, css, and html?

thank you

this is the link

https://www.grupobancolombia.com/personas/creditos/vivienda/simulador-credito-vivienda##sim-results

Comment: the videos are rendered locally i.e. on a client computer.

Comment: @BekimBacaj excuse my ignorance, can you explain even more please? you say that a video is actually created from the client side? ie a .mp4?

Comment: The demo from individeo is just a dynamic svg + static audio. The other website takes like forever to load from here, so won't be able to tell... but just use your devtools (and don't let it get stuck by click handler layer)

Comment: @Kaiido well, the concept is the same from the link that I put or from the official demo of them. So you say that the animations are made on svg, and add an audio? So you think that svg somehow becomes the video?

Comment: There is no video, just animated svg + a static audio.

Comment: @Kaiido but I see the video playback bar, I also see that if I put a certain time of the video by clicking on the progress bar, the video will be restored to that point as well as the audio. how do they achieve that? If I understand it well, I think I will know how to solve my problem. If you want, argue your answer and I will rate you

Comment: That just a programmed animation, not a video. That they use an UI that looks like video controls doesn't change that. As I said in my first comment you can just use your dev-tools to check the DOM and see how the SVG nodes are being updated by javascript. It's just too broad to show you how to do such a thing.

Comment: @Kaiido you're right! I see that it is a svg. Friend, I see that you understand enough about the subject and for now you are my only hope. I understand that the fake "video" is something very well done. I see that the "video player" bar is made in html. I also saw that they have the sound separately. It would be great for giving compliance to this answer that you could answer it and earn the bounty that will expire shortly.

I just want to understand what idea you have to make the animation.

Comment: @Kaiido I mean that if any moment of the video is selected, all the animation is reset to that point. do you have any idea how to do it? I will do my best to understand you. thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video from your question is actually a very big SVG as @Kaiido mentioned.

The [animation script](https://dtlit6slofnng.cloudfront.net/bee_001/bancolombia_individeo/v3/bee_001_bancolombia_individeo_leasing_cuota_fija_sin_comparacion_es.js?cache=202091&_=1598948867485) is very hard to understand. Here is just a part of it:
[image: example of animation]

You can see it has more that 320.000 lines of code. And we have no clue what all this numbers mean. Of course, some of them are time codes, some are coordinates, but we need reverse engineering to understand.

Your original question: `is there any way to do the same using javascript, css, and html?` of course has the answer: `yes`. Almost any animation is possible.

But we need examples. Ok, there are two possible ways to solve the animation: use existing library or create your own. If you are interested in your own, just ask in comments.

**Use library**

Google suggest: [animate.js](https://animejs.com/) library.

Here is an example of using controls (play/pause/resume/reset/set time) as it is in real video player: [click](https://animejs.com/documentation/#TLcontrols).

Here are 3 examples of using SVG: [move along the path](https://animejs.com/documentation/#motionPath), [morph to other shape](https://animejs.com/documentation/#morphing), [change line properties](https://animejs.com/documentation/#lineDrawing).

More examples using animate.js are [here](https://codepen.io/collection/XLebem?grid_type=list&cursor=ZD0wJm89MCZwPTEmdj0yMA==).

**Write your own library**

I use some kind of self-written library in one of my projects. The idea is:

- have an array of `keyframes` - this is where animation changes. Each keyframe has: time start, duration (similar to having "time end"), the list of changes (objects or their properties).
- I update the animation in `requestAnimationFrame()` loop (because my animation goes only to the future, I do not have controls)
- when current time becomes greater than new keyframe start time, I drop (remove) previous keyframe from array and apply new objects/values
- if current time is greater than keyframe start, but less than keyframe end, I use `lerp` (linear interpolation) to calculate in-between values of objects

But this description is just for the idea, so that you can create something that suits your needs.

**Audio**

I think, audio is just a normal `audio` [tag in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp):

```html
<audio id="a">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

It can be controlled with methods and properties: [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). Example:

```js
const a = document.getElementById('a');
a.currentTime = 0.8; // playing at 0.8 seconds from the start
a.play();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I expected such an answer. this library seems perfect for what I need. but you advise me to do this in svg or with html elements?

Comment: @yavg I don't know how big and complex is your animation. I think if I will have a task to create small simple video, I would use just normal HTML elements (for example `<img src="image.svg">` (if I have SVG from designer), because for me it is easier to use HTML, than SVG. On the other hand, if I have a designer near me who can help me with SVG properties, then I could use SVG also (it is not really important what property to animate). So the answer to your question is: depends on the complexity of your animation (some things easier to do in SVG).

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand, they are using an API provided by a company. What they are doing its basically taking your inputs, process them and send a bunch of info to the API as a POST request, then the API responds with a custom URL that they show to you with an iframe.

If you wanna learn more you should check the company that provides the API. [IndiVideo](https://www.bluerush.com/products/individeo/?from=individeo.com)

Also, i don't think that this is the right place to ask for something like this.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do something like that? is it possible using only css and javascript?

Comment: I don't really know how they are doing it exactly. But maybe you could achieve something similar by making a video with blank spaces and positioning the text with CSS, like an overlay. It is possible but i don't recommend it because you need to be aware of many things like: resolution of the screen, mouse events within the video element and stuff like that. Without a server to process the data i don't really think there is a decent solution to this.

Comment: the strange thing is that you can't see a .mp4 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an SVG video that takes in your data and renders it out in real time. It's definitely something anyone can build, but it would take a little less effort if you used an API.